# Spring Integration - POST call - how do I deal with timeout

Tags: http, timeout, spring-integration

**WHAT I HAVE:**

My code flow is like this:

(1) construct request
(2) POST to URL
(3) Write results to output directory

```
  @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow validateRequest() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("REQUEST_CHANNEL")
                .channel(c -> c.executor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()))
                .handle(requestModifier, "constructRequest")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("POST_URL", restTemplate)
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .mappedRequestHeaders("ab*", "TraceabilityID", authenticator.getToken())
                        .charset("UTF-8")
                        .expectedResponseType(Response.class))
                .handle(outputWriter, "writeToDir");
        }
```

**WHAT I NEED:**
    The timeout for the POST_URL is 20000 ms.
    My code tries to write the response before it receives a timeout and gives a null pointer exception.
    Which of the below approaches should I use?

```
-> Add wait() to Http.outboundGateway so that the thread waits for atleast 20 s for a response.

-> Make the whole thread sleep for 20 sec. Can you please give me an example for this?
```

Comment: @Artem Bilan, will you please be able to help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is the problem. Everything after `.channel(c -> c.executor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()))` is performed on the same thread, sequentially. The `.handle(outputWriter, "writeToDir")` won't be called until `.handle(Http.outboundGateway()` returns some result. I guess you can show your stack trace to give us more info on the matter. However you might just don't show the whole picture and you really talk about a timeout somewhere upstream.